# Encrypt the SQL query

Tags: sqlite, encryption

In my C++ program, I will invoke SQLite to execute SQL queries. But these queries are just stored as normal string constants in C++ so it is easy to be decoded via reverse engineering method. Does SQLite provide a good way to encrypt the SQL query strings while does not affect the performance when executing the queries?

Thanks

Comment: SQLite would have nothing to do with that; what you need is encrypting the strings in your application and decrypt them before you pass them to any SQLite function.